# Android phone as security camera; needs to disable safe mode

Tags: lock-screens, safe-mode

Summary:

1. I want to take pictures with the screen locked, as in the former Android. (Useful for using a phone as a security camera or a timelapse cam. Urgent need.)
2. I want to disable safe mode (without using a screen lock, using an app lock instead), since this is a huge security hole allowing a person to take control of the phone. (Also, useful for employee phones and child phones.)

I carry one phone, but use 3 phones for the house as security cameras, and 4 or more out in the field for the business as security cameras and supervision.

I just upgraded the phones, and realized after many hours that the makers of Android destroyed my number one use.  Which is to say: Android no longer allows photos to be taken with the screen locked.

Solutions:

1. I failed to find a rear camera way to take photos, which needs to be integrated into Tasker that I use for the best customization.
2. I failed to find a screen lock replacement.
3. I was able to use app locking programs to lock down my phone, but was unable to use it in safe mode, which is stupidly easy for anyone to figure out how to boot into, even for a child.  Safe mode cannot be locked with a different security level than the main mode, thus is a huge security nightmare for kids, employees, or security camera phones (now, in need of disabling the PIN pattern).  I also cannot remove my main account, since several of the key programs are paid by my main account, also, I want a paperweight for anyone stealing the phones or messing with them.

This is very short-sighted of the Android developers.